# Is it possible to fill a HashTable with multiple keys from a Linq query?

Tags: c#, linq, hashtable

I'm grabbing data from a SQL Server database into a DataTable that I convert using AsEnumerable and then separating using a series of Linq statements. My ultimate goal is to take those Linq queries and have it generate a HashTable for me. So instead of Anonymous types:

```
var facebookPosts
    = from f in results.AsEnumerable()
      where f.GetInt("SocialMediaTypeID").Equals(
          (int) SocialMediaRecordType.FacebookPost)
      select new {
          Headline = f.GetString("Headline"),
          Parameters = new Parameters(f.GetString("Parameters")),
          SocialMediaUserID = f.GetLong("SocialMediaUserID"),
          SocialMediaRecordID = f.GetLong("SocialMediaRecordID"),
          GravityScore = f.GetFloat("GravityScore"),
          NewsDate = f.GetDateTime("NewsDate", false),
          Template = "Facebook"
      };
```

I'd be able to do something like this:

```
var facebookPosts1
    = from f in results.AsEnumerable()
      where f.GetInt("SocialMediaTypeID").Equals(
          (int) SocialMediaRecordType.FacebookPost)
      select new Hashtable {
          { "Headline", f.GetString("Headline"),
            "SocialMediaUserID", f.GetLong("SocialMediaUserID"),
             etc... }                                    
      };
```

Is this possible with .NET 4.0?

**EDIT:** To clarify the question, ultimately what I'm doing with this is returning JSON to the browser. My company has created a JsonObject class that derives from a HashTable and that is what I have to use to ultimately return the Json. What I'd like to do is create one Hashtable (or JsonObject) per row in *results* that has, using the example above, a key named *Headline* with a value of *f.GetString("Headline")*, another key named *SocialMediaUserID* with a value of *f.GetLong("SocialMediaUserID")* and so on. Facebookposts would ultimately be an array or IEnumerable of HashTable or JsonObject with several key/value pairs in each. If I can't do it this way, I guess I'm stuck doing manipulation of *facebookPosts* into the proper JsonObject structure that I need? I do need to specify the names explicitly.

Comment: Any reason why you're looking for a Hashtable rather than a Dictionary? And are you still intending to specify the names explicitly, or are you expecting it to iterate over all the fields itself? If it's the latter, how would it know which "getter" to use? Are you looking for one hashtable *per row* (so an `IEnumerable<HashTable>`) or one overall? Basically, please clarify the question :)

Comment: @Rob: Will your company not allow you to use a library like JSON.NET to convert your objects to JSON strings automatically?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior: No, since they already have their own rolled. In the meantime because of time, I've resorted to Reflection to pull the information out and Json-ize it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know much about the `Hashtable` class, since `Dictionary` is the standard hashtable implementation for .NET. Something like this?

```
...
select new Dictionary<string, object>
                            {
                                {"Headline", f.GetString("Headline")},
                                {"SocialMediaUserID", f.GetLong("SocialMediaUserID")},
                                // etc..
                            };
```

Or, if you happen to have access to `System.Web`,

```
using System.Web.Routing;

facebookPosts1 = facebookPosts.Select(p => new RouteValueDictionary(p)).ToList();
```

Comment: When I try to do that, the second line where SocialMediaUserID is says "; expected". If I take out the Hashtable so it's just "select new" I get tons of errors.

Comment: @Rob: Maybe you should create a utility method for creating a Hashtable from a Dictionary? That way you can leverage all the standard .NET stuff to create the Dictionary itself, and then convert it for use in your company's JSON converter. I'm assuming that your company won't let you actually add Dictionary support to the JSON converter itself.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do doesn't fit with .NET generics, because the fields you're trying to read in won't always be of the same type. A typical use of generics is something like a `Dictionary<string, string>`, where both the types of both the key and value are known beforehand. You'd also need it nested a level deeper; if you got your example to work, it would be returning an `IEnumerable<Hashtable>`, which doesn't seem like it would be good to work with.

It sounds like what you really want is a full-fledged ORM, where it will return a collection of strongly-typed classes. Use Entity Framework, and it will handle creating the collection for you without having to do the manipulation you're trying to do here.