# Add Hashtable to end of another Hashtable

Tags: c#

I have a method which accepts a hashTable and i am using concat to add it to the end of a different hashTable, but i am getting this error:

> The type arguments for method `System.Linq.Enumerable.Concat<TSource>(this System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>)'` cannot be inferred from the usage.

I don't fully understand what this means or what i got wrong. My method looks like this:

```
public void resetCameras(Hashtable hashTable)
{
    Hashtable  ht = new Hashtable();

    ht.Add("time", 2.0f);
    ht.Add("easeType","easeInOutQuad");
    ht.Add("onupdate","UpdateSize");
    ht.Add("from",size);
    ht.Add("to",5.0f);

    if(hashTable != null) {
        ht = ht.Concat(hashTable);
    }

    iTween.ValueTo(gameObject,ht);
}
```

Hope you can help explain my mistake, still new to C# .

Comment: When you enumerate a HashTable, you *only* enumerate the **keys**.  Basically, LINQ is telling you you need *values* for the keys you're `concat`'ing.

Comment: Also note that HashTable/Dictionary does not have concept of order, so "add to the end" is really not an valid operation on these types.

Comment: @Tersosauros so i have to use a for loop ? In that case could i not just use `.Add` for each key of to the other?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov ah okay though the order doesn't matter too much thankfully :P

Comment: Related (non duplicate): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6919487/is-it-possible-to-fill-a-hashtable-with-multiple-keys-from-a-linq-query

Comment: Yes, you'll most likely need a loop of some kind.  See @Hari Prasad's answer as an example

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no easy way to `merge/concat` two `HashTables`, you have to do it in traditional way looping though each entry.

```
foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in hashTable)
{
    if(!ht.ContainsKey(entry.Key))
    {
        ht.Add(entry.Key, entry.Value);
    }   
}  

// rest of the logic
```